# yarn audit Prototype Pollution in immer coming from @storybook/react

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a react app with a dependency to @storybook/react,

```
"dependencies": {
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.3.12",
  "@storybook/addon-knobs": "6.3.1",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "6.3.1",
  "@storybook/addons": "6.3.1",
  "@storybook/react": "6.3.12",
```

when I run `yarn audit`

I am getting an error

```
Prototype Pollution in immer 
@storybook/react > react-dev-utils > immer
Patched in    │ >=9.0.6
```